# Make tar archive in parent directory

Tags: shell, tar

I am currently trying to bundle certain files in my current directory into a tar archive, and then make it so the archive is in the parent of my current directory. I'm wondering if anyone could explain to me how to do this. I understand how to bundle the files I need, but I am confused as to how I can make it so the archive is in the parent.

Currently I am using the command:

```
$ tar -tvf something.tar $( find -name "*.txt")
```

as I need to bundle files with the .txt extension.

Comment: By the way, the question and answer assume GNU findutils is used, because it omits the ([POSIX-required](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/find.html)) parameter before `-name`.

Comment: @ThomasDickey I'm going to assume that the command worked as the answer was accepted (it also worked in the environment where I tested) but I went ahead and added the `find` command with the parameters before `-name` at the end of my answer as you've made a good point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it one of a few ways:

```
tar cvf ../something.tar $( find -name "*.txt")
```

That will make it so that the files are put into `something.tar` in the directory right above.

A more long-winded way is this:

```
tar cvf /path/to/something.tar $( find -name "*.txt")
```

That uses the direct path to where you want to put the `.tar` file.

If you want actual compression:

```
tar cvfz something.tar.gz $( find -name "*.txt")
```

The `z` will put it into a `.gz` archive.

Basically, you want to use `cvf` or `cfvz` as the `c` will compress the contents into an actual archive. Using `t` as in your `tvf` command is to send the contents of the archive to standard output without extracting it which won't work as you haven't creating the `.tar` archive yet.

You may also need to escape the `*` depending on your environment:

```
tar cvf ../something.tar $( find -name "\*.txt")
```

Another update for anyone who may need this in the future:

For anyone else who wants to use this, if you don't have `findutils` installed, it will be necessary to include the path that you are searching before `-name` in the find command:

```
tar cvf ../something.tar $( find . -name "\*.txt")

tar cvf ../something.tar $( find /path/to/directory -name "\*.txt")
```

The first searches in the current directory and the second searches using the path to the directory.